# PhoneGap server starts on local interface

Tags: macos, cordova, mobile, network-programming, phonegap-build

I have a little problem. When I start `phonegap serve` I get

```
[phonegap] starting app server...
[phonegap] listening on 127.94.0.1:3000
```

But PhoneGap App listen 192.168.1.102:3000 en0, not lo0.

If I do `ifconfig lo0 down` — `phonegap serve` sarts on correct ip.

How I can to change listen ip for *phonegap server* or set priority for en0? OS X Yosemite use.